set uiview corner: Main actor-isolated property 'containerView' can not be referenced from a nonisolated context
Here's the code:
class FooCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        containerView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}


The thing is it's a subclass of UICollectionViewCell, it's already @MainActor.
    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
@MainActor open class UICollectionViewCell : UICollectionReusableView

Isn't awakeFromNib() from main thread? I can only use MainActor.assumeIsolated {} to solve this error, not quite sure this is the right way.

"Isn't awakeFromNib() from main thread" You can use MainActor.assertIsolated() to find out. — But in my opinion awakeFromNib was never a very good place to do this anyway.

@matt thanks, may I ask the reason? it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established. As the containerView is the outlet, this is why I put it there. Any suggestions? thanks!

I don't know why the instance method awakeFromNib is nonisolated (I could guess, but it would be sheer speculation). You might like to file a bug with Apple about this.
If you want to know whether it is in fact being called on the main actor, you can insert this line:
MainActor.preconditionIsolated()

That will crash your app in case you are not on the main actor at that point.
However, as an actual solution, I would suggest simply making a Task:
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    Task { @MainActor in
        // set values here
    }
}

That's safe and does no harm.
Alternatively, move your code to an override that doesn't present you with this challenge; willMove(toWindow:) might be a good place, though personally I would probably lean towards the collection view's delegate method collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:) because in that case you are saying what you mean: the corner rounding of this subview is a feature of how you want this type of cell displayed.

hi But in my opinion awakeFromNib was never a very good place to do this anyway, do you mean the set cornerRadius such code shouldn't be in awakeFromNib? May I ask the reason, thanks.

For one thing, it is very limiting; we are presuming that the only way this cell instance will come into being is from a nib (xib or storyboard). But also the corner rounding of a subview just doesn't seem germane to the business of being instantiated from a nib.

Got you, thanks!
